# How can I send data from sony smartwatch 2 to an android device

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am currently developing a simple application which required to send data from sony smartwatch 2 to a host application. I had read through the sample code and API reference which released by SONY but I cant understand how the control utility can be used.

I am try to push data to the host application and I am able to create application that sending data between two android phone through bluetooth but I am not able to transit it into sony smartwatch compatible code. Are there any hints or sample code which show me how the data/file/message can be sent from smartwatch to host application?

Comment: What data do you want to send?

Comment: I want to send a string. In addition, I would like to send the string periodically.

Comment: What is your meaning? I am trying to trigger a control event and create and send a string.

Comment: What kind of control event? It's all a bit vague for me to answer.

Comment: For example, when the user click a list item or a button, then the smartwatch send a string such as "hello" to the host application and the host application shows the string "hello" on the screen

Comment: You do know that your watch app is running on the phone? So there's no need to attempt to send data by Bluetooth.

Comment: I am sorry that I am a beginner in android and smartwatch development so could you explain more? I have read through the documentation but I can't understand how to EXTEND an android application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the project SampleControlExtension in the Sony Add-on SDK in the /samples folder.  That should show you how to draw a layout on the screen and be a good starting point to learn how to draw and display text on the device.

Comment: I have studied that sample code and I know how to trigger the event on the smartwatch but I can't understand how to control the host application on the phone from the smartwatch

Comment: I just saw that the SampleControlExtension demonstrated how can we trigger the input but I can't see the reaction of SampleControlExtension, are there any things that I missed? I saw that the documentation stated that this sample shows how the accessory supports output events but in fact, I can only see the reaction on clicking the menu button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an Activity from Control Extension, the easiest way is to use `Intent`. Here is an example of method, you can call from your extension after some event was evoked:

```
private void sendEventToActivity(String anyData) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    intent.putExtra("anyData", anyData);

    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And then override `onNewIntent` for your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String anyData = intent.getStringExtra("anyData");
}
```

This way it communicates with running activity or create a new one, if not running yet.